# Laravel create simple relationship for 2 table from single table

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have 3 models: `User` , `ChangeMoney` and `CurrencyType`, I have simple relationship with `User` and `ChangeMoney` and I want to add another relationship with `ChangeMoney` table with `CurrencyType`, but I get this error:

```
  D:\xampp\htdocs\epay-pro>php artisan migrate

  [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint (SQL
  : alter table `change_money` add constraint change_money_currency_id_foreig
  n foreign key (`currency_id`) references `currency_type` (`id`))
```

**current my migration is:**

```
Schema::create('change_money',function(Blueprint $table){
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->tinyInteger('currency_type');
    $table->string('current_money');
    $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
    $table->integer('currency');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

and I don't have any problem, now I want to add other foreign key to CurrencyType table such as:

```
Schema::create('change_money',function(Blueprint $table){
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->tinyInteger('currency_type');
    $table->string('current_money');
    $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
    $table->integer('currency_id')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('currency_id')->references('id')->on('currency_type');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

**currency_type table migration:**

```
Schema::create('currency_type',function(Blueprint $table){
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
    $table->string('currency_type','50');
    $table->char('currency_symbol','1');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Migrations in Laravel runs in order. I don't now your migrations order, but I think that your change_money migration is running first than your currency_type migration. So when the aplication try to add a foreign key in ChangeMoney table to CurrencyType table, the CurrencyType table not exist yet.

Try to create a new migration to add just the relationship between ChangeMoney table and CurrencyType table

Comment: dont any change, i get error :( i dont know whats problem. post updated. please review that

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove data from both tables ('change_money', 'currency_type').

Or you can turn off the check of foreign keys. In MySQL, or in the phpmyadmin run this:

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
```

Run migration in Laravel: `php artisan migrate`

And then again turn on check of foreign keys:

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

Answer (score 0):

PROBLEM SOLVED by split foreign key to other migration

```
class ForeignKeyBetweenChangeMoneyAndCurrencyType extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('change_money', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->integer('currency_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('currency_id')->references('id')->on('currency_type');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('change_money', function(Blueprint $table) {
            $table->dropForeign(' change_money_currency_id_foreign');
        });
    }
}
```